# Confused: Abstract Class Properties

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, properties, abstract-class

Abstract class, contains property:

```
private Box padding_;
public Box Padding
{
    get { return padding_; }
    set {
        padding_ = value;
        Model.UpdateValues( );
    }
}
```

Later I update the property of an inherited class instance, property updated:

```
ExitButton.Padding.Top = 5f;
```

The code in the setter isn't being called. I'm super confused.

Comment: Padding.Top is referring to the member `Top` of the `Padding` class, so the setter on that property will run, not the Padding property itself. You need to assign directly to `.Padding` in order to see the setter execute.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing to do with abstract classes really.  This simply doesn't call the setter for `Padding`:

```
ExitButton.Padding.Top = 5f;
```

It calls the *getter* for `Padding`, then calls the setter for the `Top` property in the `Box` object returned by that getter.